# I think there is something wrong with the algorithm for limiting questions

Tags: discussion

I asked a few questions here.

Every single one is answered and voted. Some are voted up.

Not a single bad question.

Yet I got a message don't accept questions from this account

Strange.

Any other legal forums I can ask questions?

Not that I remember.

And it doesn't happen on any other stackexchange sites.

It seems that algorithm that handles question limitation is set to be too sensitive on this site?

Answer (score 4):

Please note that the question rate-limiting takes into account all poorly-received questions, even if they are deleted.

For more information, see [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/260340).

Comment: I do not think I have any deleted questions. Do I?

Comment: Please read the meta post in full. You can view a list of your deleted questions here: https://law.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/23484

Comment: Ah I see. This question for example https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38144/anyone-ever-get-convicted-of-prostitution-for-being-in-a-sugar-relationship are there anyone ever get convicted of prostitution for being in a sugar relationship. How in the earth this question is not answerable. Either show some court cases or tell there is none. Where can I ask that?

Comment: @aeg We have questions which do not specify a jurisdiction, but those usually do not ask to prove a negative. We have some questions which ask to prove a negative, but specify jurisdictions. However, the combination of the two is most likely fatal to your question's answerability.

Comment: Proof a negative? If something is illegal it should be very easy to find some cases where people get convicted. Anyway, jurisdiction is added. If I ask anyone get convicted for larceny, well, it's easy right.

Comment: Can I see my deleted questions again? https://law.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/23484 says I have none. I want to see not recently deleted questions

Comment: nope, once they're gone they're gone. And as for proving a negative, a question like that is answerable only if you can say "yes, it's happened in this case" or "no, it's never happened" since you asked if something has ever happened. Since you can't prove that something has never happened (or at least, not easily or even with a modest amount of research) your question is very very difficult to answer.